# How to classify microprocessor

Tags: embedded, cpu, computer-science, cpu-registers, microprocessors

Hi I am new in embedded system. I do not know the true reason we classify microprocessor into 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit.

In a document I read, it explained it is because of number of the bit we used to number the address of register. But I think it is not true, because if we need 32 bit to number the register address of a processor so we must have more than 2<sup>32</sup> registers. It seem nonsense, it is too much register. So I think maybe, it is depended on the size of register or maybe the size of bus or the number of the bit, which microprocessor can work with a time.

Please help me to clarify this issued.

Comment: If you have "read" something on the subject you should include a citation, so we can see whether it is just wrong or you have misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that you have either misunderstood your reference, or it is poorly worded.  It should presumably state:

> ... number of the bits used for an address register

This means that the address range of the processor is then 2<sup>n</sup>, so perhaps your reference is referring to *memory locations* rather than *registers*.

i.e. it refers to the *bit-width* of a register, not the enumeration of a register.

However I would suggest that data path width is the more common and useful measure of processor architecture by "bit-width".  For example 8-bit processors commonly have 16 bit address buses, and 16 bit address registers.  And 16-bit 8086 devices use two 16 bit registers (32 bits) to represent a *20-bit* address, but it is neither a 20 nor 32 -bit processor.  32 and 64 bit processors *tend* to have equal address and data register widths, which may be the cause of this erroneous statement.

As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Integer_range), the natural size of an integer (i.e. the integer size that single machine instructions take as operands) is the usual method of classification in this context.

Comment: As my understanding, the classification of 8 bit or 32 bit CPU is depended on the  data path width (or bus width) of CPU. E.g: a CPU which have 8 bit bus width becasuse of the CPU can process with 8 bit in one operation. Because the bus width is 8 bit, CPU can only work with registers, which have maximum 8 bit width. And because the CPU only work with 8 bit in an operation, so it can use 8 bit for address register. In conclusion, the reason of classification CPU is 8 bit or 16 bit is the number of bit CPU can work in a operation. This caused: bus widh, register widh, register address,...

Comment: @ThanhNguyen : Your comment does not seem to be related to my answer, and looks a lot like an answer itself - you are allowed to post an answer to your own question.   Although it is not as simple as you state; for example 8080 is a 16 bit processor with an 8 bit data bus, and 68008 is a 32 bit processor with an 8 bit bus.  It is not about the bus, but about the _data_ registers, and as I said (and you have ignored) 8 and 16 bit devices typically have larger address registers (or use pairs of registers)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the address of a register but the width of the register.